# Splitting huge file based on contents with ruby

Tags: ruby, optimization, csv, io, split

Disclaimer: I'm not a programmer, never was, never learned algorithms, CS, etc. Just have to work with it.

My question is: I need to split a huge (over 4 GB) CSV file into smaller ones (then process it with `require 'win32ole'`) based on the first field. In awk it's rather easy:

```
awk -F ',' '{myfile=$1 ; print $0 >> (myfile".csv")}' KNAGYFILE.csv
```

But with `ruby` I did:

```
open('hugefile').each { |hline|
    accno = hline[0,12]
    nline = hline[13,10000].gsub(/;/,",")
    accfile = File.open("#{accno.to_s}.csv", "a")
    accfile.puts nline
    accfile.close
}
```

Then recognized that it's resource inefficient (several file open/close). I'm sure there's a better way to do it, could You explain me how?

**UPDATE:** just forgot to mention, that the file is sorted on the first column. E.g. if this is hugefile:

```
012345678901,1,1,1,1,1,1
012345678901,1,2,1,1,1,1
012345678901,1,1,A,1,1,1
012345678901,1,1,1,1,A,A
A12345678901,1,1,1,1,1,1
A12345678901,1,1,1,1,1,1
A12345678901,1,1,1,1,1,1
A12345678901,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Then I need two new files, named `012345678901.csv` and  `A12345678901.csv`.

Comment: Note, you probably want "hline[13..-1]" instead of "hline[13,10000]" unless you specifically want to truncate your lines at 10013 chars.

Comment: Wow, you say you are not a programmer and have 16k rep! amazing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your awk solution will have to open the file just as many times, so I would think you'd get the same resource usage.

You can keep the file open until $1 changes:

```
prev = nil
File.foreach('hugefile') do |hline|
  accno = hline[0,12]
  nline = hline[13,10000].gsub(/;/,",")
  if prev != accno
    accfile.close rescue nil
    accfile = File.open("#{accno.to_s}.csv", "a")
    prev = accno
  end
  accfile.puts nline
end
```

Comment: Do AWK reopens (and closes) the file on every line it's processing? Anyway - thanks for your answer, I'll test it at work, but yeah, it looks what I was looking for.

Comment: No, I meant when you "print $0 >> somefile", that will open, append and close the file.

Comment: I see, but my awk solution does it for every line IMO.

Comment: I was just reading the nawk man page (for a different problem) and found that output redirection only opens the file if it's not already open, and keeps it open until explicitly closed.  So, +1 for awk.

Answer (score 1):

This should get around the multi-open-write-close issue, although it might run into problems if the number of files becomes large; I can't say, I never had hundreds of files open for write!

The first line is the important one: for each new key encountered it opens a new file and stores it against that key in the hash. The last line closes all the files opened.

```
files = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = File.open("#{k}.csv", 'w+') }
open('hugefile').each do |hline|
  files[hline[0,12]].puts hline[13,10000].gsub(/;/,",")
end
files.each { |n, f| f.close }
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I'll benchmark it at work as well. (And yes, I need to open some 2000 files.)

Comment: Yikes! 2000 files? I just thought - is the input sorted? If so, glenn's solution is probably optimal.

Comment: Mike's solution is more "Ruby way". If keeping 2000 open files handles simultaneously will yield performance problems, you can extend `files` Hash functionality to close some files if it becomes too large.

It is all excessive, if input is sorted.